# how to make a robot follow a line in ros?

Tags: ros, path, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I have to make a robot follow the path in the simulator using ros
and I really don't know how to start, please help me in this project**

**It will be a better if you could give me instruction step by step to make this robot follow the path**

Thank you to all of you and God bless you all :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216143/how-to-make-a-robot-follow-a-line-in-ros-?/) by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2015-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Denso I'll need more details like are you using a world model with obstacles and are you trying to make the robot move from one point to another point (random points in the world). How are you doing the localization for the robot? Are you planning to use kalman filter for localization or are you using paricle filter?

I think that ROS/GazeboSim is the best alternative to accomplish tasks like this. Did you have a look at that?  You may want to take a look at Gazebo tutorials. You will need to learn how to use path planning (deliberative navigation) and reactive navigation. There are some stacks in ROS that will facilitate your job. Take a look at motion planning (OMPL stack) and navigation stack Motion planners and Stack navigation.

If you know tha map of the environment already then you can use a motion planning algorithm to compute the path between the two points.

---

Originally posted by [staljbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/17761/staljbs/) with karma: 116 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-19**:
i would like to create a simulator in ros, that's allow me to create a path for the robot and the robot have to follow this path from point A to point B

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-19**:
**please respond to me with some information so i could start with this project as soon as possible
I really appreciate your help and time ;)**

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2015-08-20**:
first you schoud say how the robot have to see the Line?  IF it is a camera you can publisch the view of a simulated camera to ros and work with open CV

http://wiki.ros.org/cob_gazebo_worlds/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20world
http://www.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_world&cat=build_world